# Create a remove header function in Pyspark for RDDs

Tags: function, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to create a function that removes the header for RDDS

```
def remHeader(data):
   header = data.first()
   data = data.filter(lambda x: x != header)
```

However, I'n not getting anything while executing the function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: return your data and `data.collect()`.

Comment: I want to save it in the same RDD. When I do that and then run my function the header doesn't get deleted.

Comment: You can see the result by collect rdd but the rdd not to be saved with collect. just for check your result at the middle step.

Comment: I want the rd to be saved. How can I do that?